# Plotting Geotagged Photos in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, photos, geotag, plot

I am not a MapInfo user, but I have been asked whether that software can plot geotagged photos and link the images to the points (eg, click on a point and the photo pops up)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an option to add 'Hotlinks' to objects and/or labels in MapInfo. You can point the hotlink to a field in the data containing the relevant filepath/url, then using the Hotlink tool you can click on any map object containing a Hotlink and it will launch the file/url with the appropriate application. You can read more about it in a section of the MapInfo Help entitled 'Creating Active Objects'.